# Could not pass value in URL query string using Django and Python

Tags: python, django

I need to pass session id in URL query string after login using Django and Python but in my case I am getting some error. My code is below.

```
def loginsave(request):
    """This function helps to login the user """

    if request.method == 'POST':
        password = request.POST.get('pass')
        uname = request.POST.get('uname')
        per = User.objects.all().filter(
            Q(password__icontains=password) & Q(uname__icontains=uname)).count()
        if per > 0:
            user = User.objects.filter(
                Q(password__icontains=password) & Q(uname__icontains=uname))
            for use in user:
                uid = use.id
                user_name = use.uname
            request.session['id'] = uid
            request.session['sess'] = dict(dt=str(datetime.now()),
                                    value='session')
            request.session['sess_id'] = 'abcd1234'
            return render(request, 'bookingservice/home.html',
                                {'count': per, 'username': user_name})
        else:
            return render(request, 'bookingservice/login.html', {})
```

This is my login function here I am creating session id and I need to pass it over URL. My menu list is given below.

```
<a href="{% url 'home' %}?token={{request.session["sess_id"]}}">Home</a>
<a href="{% url 'booking' %}">Add Booking</a>
 <a href="{% url 'personal' %}">Add Personal Info</a>
```

I am doing like this but here I am getting the following error.

```
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '["sess_id"]' from 'request.session["sess_id"]'
```

Here I need after login the session id should come over every page URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`{{request.session["sess_id"]}}`

to

```
{{ request.session.sess_id }}
```

usually the template language of django works this way. Here a dot in a variable name signifies a lookup.When the template system encounters a dot in a variable name, it tries the following lookups, in this order:

```
Dictionary lookup. Example: request.session["bar"]
Attribute lookup. Example: request.session.bar
List-index lookup. Example: request.session[bar]
```

You can find more at [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in template, it should read (mind the quotes):

```
<a href="{% url 'home' %}?token={{request.session['sess_id']}}">Home</a>
<a href="{% url 'booking' %}">Add Booking</a>
<a href="{% url 'personal' %}">Add Personal Info</a>
```